# How do I get / retrieve my REST data using ember-data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js

I've been scouring for documentation on the REST adapter that is packaged with ember data, but I can't seem to find any information on how to actually have ember make the json request to the server, or how to retrieve or access the data once it has made the request using this adapter ( the documentation on the ember-data page seems to all be about rolling your own adapter, besides a small paragraph on how to specify if you need to disable bulk commits, though maybe I'm just missing something )

Comment: I was just checking out Ember for the first time yesterday, so I claim no expertise whatsoever, however I recall that there's a separate library that you need present in order to interact with a backend REST API.  Check for that.  And while you're at it, you might also check out Backbone.js, which seems way further along, to my eyes.

Comment: The library you're thinking of is the "ember-data", which comes with the rest adapter that I mention, I have that much implemented. I'm actually moving this project away from backbone in hopes of a little more structure ( which ember for the most part actually delivers on )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to tell your store to use the `DS.RESTAdapter` and this handles the communication with your server via AJAX calls, see a basic example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Aj6Pf/)

You can get a basic overview how the `RESTAdapter` is used in the [tests](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/rest_adapter_test.js).

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.store = DS.Store.create({
    revision: 3,
    adapter: DS.RESTAdapter.create({
        ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
            console.log(arguments);
        }
    })
});

App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
});

App.Person.createRecord({
});

// tell the store to contact REST service
App.store.commit();
```

​

Comment: Thank You Pangratz, I of course didn't even think to look at the tests, but they seem to cover most of what I was wondering.

Comment: They are a very good resource of what should be done in which way. Glad I could help.